# Javax.Mail Authenticator not found on Linux

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-mail

Hello Guys have written a simple java project using using java mail API to send mail.
It works perfectly , Now the problem is I need to take the class file and run it on Linus os using a cron tab job. (Task Scheduler)

when using the code

Java Sendmail on linux I get the error Javax.Mail Authenticator not found.

I just copied the class file and all the jar file in the same folder and ran it on linux OS.

My question is how do I use the javamail api on linux terminal.

I mean the same equivalent of going to netbeans project and adding the jar files to your libraries.. this is a very tricky one for me.

Any hint will be apprieciated

I have tried java -jar /pathto/jarfile sendmail

Comment: on linux you'll have to use the java command line and specify the classpath (where java will search for libraries). Your error message seems to be a classpath problem. see http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/linux-cmd.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys found it ..first step was to copy the jar files into the folder where u have the class file.

and use the command

java -classpath .:mail.jar:imap.jar:dsn.jar:smtp.jar:gimap.jar:mailapi.jar:pop3.jar email.Email

the class is Email and i added all the jar files.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a runnable jar to execute it using **java -jar yourJAR**

Otherwise use **java -cp pathtoyourjar:otherjar MainClass**

If you have all the required jar in one folder you can use wildcard class path lik

**java -cp /lib/*:YOUR-JAR-FILE-PATH MainClass**

If you want to run your job in background look at command **nohup** (Linux specific)

Comment: Thanks I didnt ask the question the right way ..the questin should be more like Java: problem running a jar file in command line. I have tried java -jar mail.jar sendmail it says no main manifest attribute

Comment: no main that means your manifest file doesn't contain MainClass entry. Lik this-  Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass or you can refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html if you are using eclipse or my-eclipse use option of runnable jar